# Finding area bounded by two graphs of functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that someone posted this same question before here, because i found it, but i couldn't find the answer about this example that i was looking for, so i will post everything i did so far:

I have to find area bounded by graphics of functions

$y_1=x\sqrt{4x-x^2}$

$y_2=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$

First, i found domains, the are the same for both of these functions $[0,4]$

Now that i have the domains i need to find intersection points, and there's one $x=1$ now , it means that graph of one function is above the graph of the other one up to on interval $[0,1]$ and after that they switch their roles on $[1,4]$

It turns out that  $y_1>y_2   (\forall x \in [0,1])$

and $y_2>y_1   (\forall x \in [1,4])$

So i have to find the following integral:

$P=\int_0^1 (\sqrt{4x-x^2} - x\sqrt{4x-x^2})dx  +  \int_1^4(x\sqrt{4x-x^2}-\sqrt{4x-x^2})dx$

This is equal to

$P=\int_0^1 (1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx - \int_1^4 (1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx$

so i actually have to solve

$\int (1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx = \int \sqrt{4x-x^2} - \int x\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx $

the first one can be easily solved using substitution $x=2sint$ and the second one can be solved using the same substitution except that we will have i little bit different solution.

It turns out that the solution of the first integral is

$2arcsin\frac{x-2}{2} + \frac{(x-2)\sqrt{4x-x^2}}{2}$

and for the second one:

$4arcsin\frac{x-2}{2} + (x-2)\sqrt{4x-x^2} + \frac{\sqrt{(4x-x^2)^3}}{3}$

Now when i insert the values i have:

$P=\int_0^1 \sqrt{4x-x^2}dx - \int_0^1 x\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx =[ 2arcsin\frac{1-2}{2} + \frac{(1-2)\sqrt{4*1-1^2}}{2} ] - [2arcsin\frac{0-2}{2} + \frac{(1-2)\sqrt{4*0-0^2}}{2}] - [2arcsin\frac{4-2}{2} + \frac{(4-2)\sqrt{4*4-4^2}}{2}] + [2arcsin\frac{1-2}{2} + \frac{(1-2)\sqrt{4*1-1^2}}{2}]$

In this large expression i have $arcsin(\frac{-1}{2})$ Now, i know that $arcsin(\frac{-1}{2}) = \frac{7\pi}{6} and \frac{11\pi}{6} $ my question is, which one i should use? In my solution, i used $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ And $\frac{11\pi}{6} = \frac{-\pi}{6}$ what about that?

And at the end, the most important thing, i got solution $P=\frac{-2\pi}{3}$ which is the negative value, but area can't be negative, what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very long but I tried to give a lot of details and a different approach, to highlight some interesting things (IMHO) about integration techniques.

We have two functions:

$$\begin{cases}
&y_{1}:[0,4]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto y_{1}(x)=x\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\\
&y_{2}:[0,4]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto y_{2}(x)=\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}
\end{cases}$$

As you correctly noted, $y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\geq 0\iff(x-1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\geq 0\iff x\geq 1$. And we deduce $y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\geq 0\iff x\in[1,4]$ because of the domain condition. Similarly, we get $y_{2}(x)-y_{1}(x)\geq 0\iff x\in[0,1]$.

Now, as you did, by denoting $P$ the area determined by the respective graphs of these functions:

\begin{align*}
P&=\int_{0}^{1}(y_{2}(x)-y_{1}(x))\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{4}(y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x))\text{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{4}(x-1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x
\end{align*}

You cannot put them together! You can put two integrals together if you have the following. Let $f$ be a Riemann-integrable function over an interval $[a,b]$ and let $c\in (a,b)$. Then:

$$\int_{a}^{c}f(x)\text{d}x+\int_{c}^{b}f(x)\text{d}x=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{d}x$$

Here, you have two different functions! One is $x\mapsto (1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}$ and the other is the "opposite" function: $x\mapsto (x-1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}$ and that's normal since one corresponds to $y_{1}-y_{2}$ and the other $y_{2}-y_{1}$. You have to compute the integrals separately. Before doing it, it is useful to "make appear" the derivative of $(4x-x^{2})$, as follows:

\begin{align*}
P&=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{4}(x-1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(\tfrac{1}{2}(4-2x)-1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{4}(-\tfrac{1}{2}(4-2x)+1)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x\\
&=\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x\right]+\left[-\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{4}\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\right]
\end{align*}

Let's compute the following:

$$\int\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x=\int\sqrt{4-(x-2)^{2}}\text{d}x\to\int2\cos(t)\sqrt{4-(2\sin(t)+2-2)^{2}}\text{d}t$$

where we have used $x=2\sin(t)+2$. It gives:

\begin{align*}
\int2\cos(t)\sqrt{4-(2\sin(t)+2-2)^{2}}\text{d}t &= \int 4\cos(t)\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(t)}\text{d}t\\
&=\int 4\cos(t)\vert\cos(t)\vert\text{d}t
\end{align*}

Here, the bounds of the integral do matter, because $\sqrt{f^2}=\vert f\vert$ so that we have to know where $\cos(t)$ is negative and positive.

**For the first bounds $[0,1]$**

We have $x=2\sin(t)+2$. When $x=0$, we have $-2=2\sin(t)\hspace{0.5em} (A)$, so that $t=-\pi/2$. For $x=1$, we have $-1/2=\sin(t)\hspace{0.5em} (B)$ so that $t=-\pi/6$. How can we choose these values? The mapping $t\mapsto 2\sin(t)+2$ has to be bijective! For that, if you choose $-\pi/2$ for the equation $(A)$, you must choose the $t$ from $(B)$ in order to keep this mapping bijective! Intuitively, you take the closest value to $-\pi/2$ that gives a bijection and is a solution to $(B)$, i.e. $-\pi/6$. You can check that

$$\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{6}\right]\mapsto[0,1]:t\mapsto 2\sin(t)+2$$

is bijective. But now that we explicitly know the range of $t$, we have to compute the values where $\cos(t)$ is positive or negative for $t\in[-\pi/2;-\pi/6]$. Fortunately, $\cos(t)\geq 0\forall t\in[-\pi/2,-\pi/6]$, so that $\vert \cos(t)\vert=\cos(t)\forall t\in[-\pi/2,-\pi/6]$ and the integral can be rewritten as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6}2\cos(t)\sqrt{4-(2\sin(t)+2-2)^{2}}\text{d}t &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} 4\cos(t)\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(t)}\text{d}t\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} 4\cos(t)\vert\cos(t)\vert\text{d}t\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} 4\cos^{2}(t)\text{d}t\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} 4\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}\text{d}t\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} (2+2\cos(2t))\text{d}t\\
&=(2t+\sin(2t))\big\vert_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6}\\
&=\frac{-\pi}{3}+\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{3}\right)-\left(-\pi+\sin(-\pi)\right)\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\geq 0
\end{align*}

And note that you must have a positive result because the integral of a positive function must be positive!

**For the second bounds $[1,4]$**

The mapping

$$[\alpha,\beta]\to[1,4]:t\mapsto 2\sin(t)+2$$

must be bijective, so that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be determined accordingly. When $x=1$, we get $t=-\pi/6$ as previously. When $x=4$, we get $2=2\sin(t)$, so that $t=\pi/2+2k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$). Intuitively, you take $k\geq 0$ such that $[-\pi/6,\pi/2+2k\pi]$ is the smallest possible. Here, obviously, $k=0$. It gives $\alpha=-\pi/6$ and $\beta=\pi/2$. You can check that

$$[-\pi/6,\pi/2]\to[1,4]:t\mapsto 2\sin(t)+2$$

is bijective. Again, fortunately, on this interval, $\cos(t)\geq 0$, so that:

\begin{align*}\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/2}2\cos(t)\sqrt{4-(2\sin(t)+2-2)^{2}}\text{d}t 
&=(2t+\sin(2t))\big\vert_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\\
&=\pi+\sin(\pi)+\frac{\pi}{3}+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\geq 0
\end{align*}

**Summarize**

We had

\begin{align*}
P&=\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x-\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x}\right]+\left[-\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\color{blue}{\int_{1}^{4}\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x-\color{red}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right]+\left[-\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x+\color{blue}{\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right]\\
\end{align*}

Now, it remains to compute

\begin{align*}
\int(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x&\to\int \sqrt{t}\text{d}t
\end{align*}

where we used $t=4x-x^{2}$, so that when $x=1$, $t=3$ and when $x=4$, $t=0$. It gives:

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{4}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x&=\int_{3}^{0} \sqrt{t}\text{d}t\\
&=-\int_{0}^{3}t^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\text{d}t\\
&=-\left[\frac{2}{3}t^{\tfrac{3}{2}}\right]\Big\vert_{0}^{3}\\
&=-\frac{2}{3}3\sqrt{3}\\
&=-2\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}

Now, when $x=0$, $t=0$, so that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}(4-2x)\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}\text{d}x&=\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{t}\text{d}t\\
&=2\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}

which gives

\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot2\sqrt{3}-\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)- \frac{1}{2}\cdot2\sqrt{3}+\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\\
&=3\sqrt{3}+2\frac{\pi}{3}\\
&\approx 7.291
\end{align*}

which is correct, [according to WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(x-1)sqrt(4x-x%C2%B2)+from+1+to+4+%2B+integral+(1-x)sqrt(4x-x%C2%B2)+from+0+to+1).

Comment: This is the best answer i received here, not just on this question. Not only it helped me with this problem, but you also explained a lot of things that were confusing for me and that can be implemented on various other problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Your comment is very encouraging, I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is incorrect, you could check that on wolfram alpha.

For
$$\int_0^1 (1-x)\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx$$

Because $4x-x^2=4-(x-2)^2$

Let $x-2=2\sin t$

$$
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} (-1-2\sin t)(2\cos t)(2\cos t)dt \\
&=-2\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} (2\cos^2t -1+1)dt + 8\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/3} \cos^2 t d(\cos t) \\
&=-\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/6} \cos (2 t) d(2t) -2(-\pi/6+\pi/2) +\frac 83[ \cos^3 (-\pi/6)- \cos^3 (-\pi/2)]\\
&=-sin(-2\pi/6)+\sin(-2\pi/2) -\frac{2\pi}3 +\sqrt 3\\
&= \frac{3\sqrt 3}2-\frac {2\pi} 3
\end{align}
$$

You can use other methods to integrate it, a tip for you is that the range of arcsine is defined on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, so you don't need to consider different values for arcsine. I will leave the second integral for you to evaluate

Answer (score 1):

> $P=\int_0^1 \sqrt{4x-x^2}dx - \int_0^1 x\sqrt{4x-x^2}dx $

You should have
$$P=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4x-x^2}\ dx-\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{4x-x^2}\ dx\color{red}{-\left(\int_{1}^{4}\sqrt{4x-x^2}\ dx-\int_{1}^{4}x\sqrt{4x-x^2}\ dx\right)}$$

Also, $\arcsin(-1/2)=-\pi/6$ because the range of usual principal value of arcsine is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

I think you can continue from here.